# Django Admin Model ArrayField Change Delimiter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-postgresql

My model looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class Trigger(models.Model):
    solutions = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True, null=True), blank=True, null=True, help_text='some helpful text')
```

This allows me to enter a list of solutions separated by a comma by default. For example: I can enter in that textfield:

```
1. watch out for dust.,
2. keep away from furry animals.,
```

This does create a list of  two separate string items. However, if a solution text itself contains a comma, for example:

```
1. cockroaches, polens and molds might be harmful.
```

This will create two separate solution lines, because of the existence of a comma in that sentence.

How do I tell django to use a different delimiter than comma as it would be almost certainly a part of sentences. How can I use a separator like '|'? I looked inside the arrayfield class, but it doesn't allow any separator.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider this a duplicate, but it may point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426010/better-arrayfield-admin-widget

Comment: that question is a superset of mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some relevant documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#simplearrayfield

If you're using built in forms on the admin site, or using a ModelForm without customising any fields then the field is probably automatically using the `SimpleArrayField` form field.  It looks like you can override the delimiter character.  The documentation states this caveat:

> The field does not support escaping of the delimiter, so be careful in cases where the delimiter is a valid character in the underlying field. The delimiter does not need to be only one character.

---

Anyways, you could do this by providing a custom form like this...

```
# forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Trigger


class TriggerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['solutions'].delimiter = '|'  # Or whichever other character you want.

    class Meta:
        model = Trigger
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

And if this is for use in the admin site...

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import TriggerForm
from .models import Trigger


@admin.register(Trigger)
class TriggerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TriggerForm
```

Answer (score 4):

Slightly cleaner solution (without overriding the `__init__` in the Form class) would be to just specify the field on the form.

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.forms import SimpleArrayField
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import CharField
from django.forms.widgets import Textarea

class TriggerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    solutions = SimpleArrayField(CharField(), delimiter='|', widget=Textarea())
```

This way you can easily choose to go with, for example [`SplitArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#splitarrayfield) or specify different widget for the field.